# Select Data from 1 Table and Fill in rest from another where some entries from A don't Appear on B

Tags: sql

I'm an SQL Novice and have gotten by with my needs with simple selects and merging by using a WHERE (A.Field1 = B.Field1) however I now have a situation where I have Table A which contains a list of substructures and each component type on the substructure something like this

```
+------------------+-------+
| Substructure     | Ident |
+------------------+-------+
| Some Thing       | 01    |
+------------------+-------+
| Some Thing       | 02    |
+------------------+-------+
| Some Other Thing | 01    |
+------------------+-------+
| Some Other Thing | 06    |
+------------------+-------+
```

I have a second table that contains information about  each of these components, however this table only contains information for which the information has been filled in for at least 1 of the components on the line.

Table B

```
+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+
| Substructure | Ident | Task Complete | Reading |
+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+
| Some Thing   | 01    | Y             | 09      |
+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+
| Some Thing   | 02    | N             |         |
+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+
```

Now what I've tried

```
SELECT 
     A.Substructure
     A.Ident
     B.Substructure
     B.Ident
     B.Task_Complete
     B.Reading
From A,B Where (A.Substructure = B.Substructure)
```

Which obviously only takes out where the substructures is exist in both lists. 
What I'm looking forward is a method of taking all the Substructures that exist in A and matching it with the results in B. Where results don't exist in B these can be any form of null value.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `LEFT` join

```
SELECT 
     A.Substructure
     A.Ident
     B.Substructure
     B.Ident
     B.Task_Complete
     B.Reading
From A
LEFT JOIN ON B A.Substructure = B.Substructure
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
     A.Substructure
     A.Ident
     B.Substructure
     B.Ident
     B.Task_Complete
     B.Reading
From A
     left join B on (A.Substructure = B.Substructure)
```